# Storing vCard/vcf contact records in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vcf-vcard

I want to create a SQL table to store contact records in [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) format. Does anyone have a ready SQL CREATE script for this?

Comment: Curious about the solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a script, but I do have mySQL that you can use. Before that I should mentioned that there seem to be two logical approaches to storing vCards in SQL:

1. Store the whole card and let the database search, (possibly) huge text strings, and process them in another part of your code or even client side. e.g.

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vcards` (
   `name_or_letter` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
   `vcard` text NOT NULL,
   `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`username`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

Probably easy to implement, (depending on what you are doing with the data) though your searches are going to be slow if you have many entries.
If this is just for you then this might work, (if it is any good then it is *never* just for you.) You can then process the vCard client side or server side using some beautiful module that you share, (or someone else shared with you.)

I've watched vCard evolve and *know* that there is going to be
some change at /some/ time in the future so I use three tables.

The first is the card, (this mostly links back to my existing tables - if you don't need this then yours can be a cut down version).
The second are the card definitions, (which seem to be called profile in vCard speak).
The last is all the actual data for the cards.

Because I let DBIx::Class, (yes I'm one of those) do all of the database work this, (three tables) seems to work rather well for me,
(though obviously you can tighten up the types to match [rfc2426](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2426.txt) more closely,
but for the most part each piece of data is just a text string.)

The reason that I don't normalize out the address from the person is that I already have an
address table in my database and these three are just for non-user contact details.

```
 CREATE TABLE `vCards` (   
 `card_id` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
 `card_peid` int(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'link back to user table',   
 `card_acid` int(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'link back to account table',      
 `card_language` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'en en_GB',
 `card_encoding` varchar(32) DEFAULT 'UTF-8' COMMENT 'why use anything else?',
 `card_created` datetime NOT NULL,  
 `card_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`card_id`) )
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='These are the contact cards';

   create table vCard_profile (
    vcprofile_id int(255) unsigned auto_increment NOT NULL,
    vcprofile_version enum('rfc2426') DEFAULT "rfc2426" COMMENT "defaults to vCard 3.0",
    vcprofile_feature char(16) COMMENT "FN to CATEGORIES",
    vcprofile_type enum('text','bin') DEFAULT "text" COMMENT "if it is too large for vcd_value then user vcd_bin",
  PRIMARY KEY (`vcprofile_id`)
) COMMENT "These are the valid types of card entry";
INSERT INTO vCard_profile VALUES('','rfc2426','FN','text'),('','rfc2426','N','text'),('','rfc2426','NICKNAME','text'),('','rfc2426','PHOTO','bin'),('','rfc2426','BDAY','text'),('','rfc2426','ADR','text'),('','rfc2426','LABEL','text'),('','rfc2426','TEL','text'),('','rfc2426','EMAIL','text'),('','rfc2426','MAILER','text'),('','rfc2426','TZ','text'),('','rfc2426','GEO','text'),('','rfc2426','TITLE','text'),('','rfc2426','ROLE','text'),('','rfc2426','LOGO','bin'),('','rfc2426','AGENT','text'),('','rfc2426','ORG','text'),('','rfc2426','CATEGORIES','text'),('','rfc2426','NOTE','text'),('','rfc2426','PRODID','text'),('','rfc2426','REV','text'),('','rfc2426','SORT-STRING','text'),('','rfc2426','SOUND','bin'),('','rfc2426','UID','text'),('','rfc2426','URL','text'),('','rfc2426','VERSION','text'),('','rfc2426','CLASS','text'),('','rfc2426','KEY','bin');

create table vCard_data (
    vcd_id int(255) unsigned auto_increment NOT NULL,
    vcd_card_id int(255) NOT NULL,
    vcd_profile_id int(255) NOT NULL,
    vcd_prof_detail varchar(255) COMMENT "work,home,preferred,order for e.g. multiple email addresses",
    vcd_value varchar(255),
    vcd_bin blob COMMENT "for when varchar(255) is too small",
    PRIMARY KEY (`vcd_id`)
) COMMENT "The actual vCard data";
```

This isn't the best SQL but I hope that helps.

Comment: [This other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352/address-book-db-schema/11313185#11313185) might also help you.

Answer (score 0):

In general there are two ways of implementation

The simplest way is a one table approach. 
It'll work for most cases (I would guess 80%)
The one will include all vcard values, object names, types etc. The big advantage is the speed and simplicity. It might also fit for nosql databases... 
It is messy though...

The 2nd way is the relational way, that is tables for types, objects etc
It is not as simple as the one table approach, but it does take the SQL advantages:  minimum data repetitiveness, the ability to slice and dice quickly etc.

I have recently tried to implement such approach myself in MySQL
[vcards MySQL implementation](https://github.com/GuyLou/vcards)